# imagemagick -colorspace Gray splits image into three

Tags: imagemagick

I'm running ImageMagick 6.7.7-6 on an AMI EC2. I am executing the following command in a shell script executed on the command line:

```
convert orig.jpg -colorspace Gray final.jpg
```

or

```
convert orig.jpg -type Grayscale final.jpg
```

The expected result was for the image to be turned into a gray scale image. The result I get is quite different. It is split into three images and there are still small amounts of colour in it ?!?

orig.jpg:

[image]

final.jpg:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain what's happening here. Both your commands work for me and my version of ImageMagick (6.7.8-0 2012-07-12 Q16) on Mac OS X.

That's why I think you are encountering a bug in your version of IM.

Which is your version of IM?